# MigLayout for design android Forms

Tags: android, android-layout, miglayout

I am on a project. My instructor has told me to use `MigLayout` to design the forms in android. I am finding it difficult to find proper examples and while Using `Eclipse` for development its showing errors that `android perfix is required to use the attributes`.

please help me with some examples..
code that i pasted from the source site,mig4android.

```
 <com.saynomoo.mig4android.MigLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          layout_constraints="wrap 4, debug 1"
          column_constraints="[]15[75px]25[min]25[]"
          row_constraints="[]15"
    >
 <TextView android:text="label1" component_constraints="skip"/>
 <TextView android:text="label2" />
 <TextView android:text="label3" component_constraints="wrap"/>
 <TextView android:text="label4" />
 <TextView android:text="label5" component_constraints="wmin 30"/>
 <TextView android:text="label6" component_constraints="wmin 30"/>
 <TextView android:text="label7" component_constraints="wmin 30"/>

 </com.saynomoo.mig4android.MigLayout>
```

The component_constraints gave the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you forget to add **android** word before any attribute in xml file.

For example-

```
id="@+id/my_location"
```

You need to write android before `id` like below.

```
android:id="@+id/my_location"
```

Your code is perfect. **But "skip" in component_constraints appears to be ignored. I had to manually add place holder to the layout to "fill in" empty spots. I tried "skip 1" and that also had no impact.**

For more information see following link.

[Skip as a constraint is not working](https://github.com/saynomoo/mig4android/issues/14)

Comment: in miglayout there are attributes that doesn't contain the android prefix.that's why i am facing the issue if i get an example then i will be very thankful.